# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'accueil' not found

Tags: r

I try ti create a RandomForst model using R for sentiment analysis : 
Here the code :

```
data = as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm_train), stringsAsFactors = T)
>data
      accueil bon depuis banque client très service conseiller agence a plus je
634         0   0      0      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
3802        0   0      0      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
16739       0   0      0      0      0    1       0          0      0 0    0  1
20992       0   0      0      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
4742        0   0      0      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
5104        0   0      1      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
6978        1   1      0      1      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
21630       0   2      0      0      0    0       1          0      0 0    0  0
13606       0   0      0      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
21910       0   0      0      0      0    0       0          1      0 0    0  0
8184        0   0      0      0      0    0       0          0      0 0    0  0
...

Note = train[['Note.Reco']]

> Note

[1]  9 10  9  0 10  8 10  7 10 10  5  5  8  8  2  9  8  0 10 10  8  0  8  7  7  6  9 10  8  9  5 10 10  0  5  3  2  8  8  1  7  6  0  8  9  0  5  5  8  6  8
 [52]  8  7  8  9  9  9 10  5  4  5  8  8  8  9  9 10  9  8  4 10  9  8  8  8  8  5  0  9  8  7  5  3  2 10  8 10  9  0 10  6 10  8  5  9 10  1  8  9  1

reviews.test = test$reason

   [1] "Pas assez service......"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   [2] "Pour résidant s....."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   [3] " emails, réponses ...."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   [4] "Même ...."      

review.test_DF = as.data.frame(reviews.test,stringsAsFactors = T)   

reviews.svm = randomForest(Note~.,  data) 
pred.svm = predict(reviews.svm, review.test_DF,  type="class")
```

I get this error :

```
> pred.svm = predict(reviews.svm, review.test_DF,  type="class")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'accueil' not found
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

thank you in advance

Comment: Your test dataset `review.test_DF` has only only column. I would recommend reading vignette for `caret` package `library("caret") ;vignette("caret")` to understand the train/test split process, model fitting and prediction process

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes I know that " test dataset review.test_DF has only only column.", it s the column thzt contains review .. I don't know why it is the problem?

Comment: If you will work through the examples of the vignette the problem will then be obvious. The first step is to split the input dataset into training and testing(holdout) dataset, then train the model on the training portion. The model is then fit to testing dataset and the model  predictions are compared with actual values to compute accuracy metrics. All of these are contained in the vignette or you can work through [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf)

Comment: Ok, and in my example I did like this...